# How can I get Blender to notify me when a render completes?

Tags: rendering, add-on

I'm running Blender v3.x on MacOS 12.x

I'd like to be notified, ideally by a push notification on my iPhone when a render has completed, similar to how Adobe notifies when After Effects completes.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: search for blender render complete notification addon

Comment: Is that the only/best way? Involves setting up a gmail account specifically for sending, reducing security on the gmail account, etc etc. No other solution using Growl/Prowl or something?

Comment: Please be a little more patient with us. We can't give you everything at once, and *one* suggestion is probably not all you're going to get anyway.

Comment: checkout here: https://blenderartists.org/t/can-blender-send-a-notification-email-or-sms-when-renders-are-finished/636949/12.   looks like you have to pay one time 5$ and then you can have it ;)

Comment: and here is a gmail solution, if email is ok https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/fw8k9z/blender_render_complete_notification_addon_free/

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same issue:

I ended up installing "Render Notifier" by Neeraj Lagwankar. It costs $15, and pushes via Telegram. Works pretty well so far.

https://blendermarket.com/products/render-notifier